# ADD COLUMN with CONSTRAINT

Tags: mysql, primary-key, rdbms, alter-table, unique-key

I have a table name Stu_d. In this, I have created 3 columns {Stu_id INT PRIMARY KEY, Name VARCHAR(20), Roll_no INT(5)}.
I need to add 1 more column with the name of Mobile_no with INT data type and have a constraint of UNIQUE KEY.
With the help of ALTER TABLE.

I have tried this syntax:-

ALTER TABLE table_name
ADD COLUMN column_name datatype(size),
ADD constraint_name column_name;

ALTER TABLE Stu_d
ADD COLUMN Mobile_no INT(10),
ADD UNIQUE KEY (Mobile_no);

ERROR 1072 (42000): Key column 'Moblie_no' doesn't exist in table

Then i try :-

```
 ALTER TABLE Stu_d
 ADD COLUMN Mobile_no INT(10),
 UNIQUE KEY (Moblie_no);
```

ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'UNIQUE KEY (Moblie_no)' at line 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax for this is

```
ALTER TABLE Stu_d ADD COLUMN Mobile_no INT(10) UNIQUE ;
```

if you want to name the constraint then use

```
ALTER TABLE Stu_d ADD COLUMN Mobile_no INT(10) ;
ALTER TABLE Stu_d ADD CONSTRAINT uq_Mobile_no UNIQUE (Mobile_No);
```